# Stack Is not Working if is Used Google Map in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting weird Issue after Migrate my project to Flutter 3.0. Perviously I was showing DropDown above Google Map using Stack Widget and it was perfectly working. But now Dropdown is not showing. here is My code.

```
Stack(children: [
                            currentPostion == null
                                ? Center(
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Please Wait While we are fetching\n Your Current Location",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : _buildGoogleMap(context),
                            _dropDownButton(),
                            _searchbar()
                          ]);
```

and this is code for GoogleMap, buildDropDown and Search Bar

```
Widget _buildGoogleMap(BuildContext context) {
    const double CAMERA_ZOOM = 13;
    const double CAMERA_TILT = 0;
    const double CAMERA_BEARING = 30;

    CameraPosition initialLocation = CameraPosition(
        zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
        bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
        tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
        target: currentPostion);
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          compassEnabled: true,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
          markers: _markers,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          onMapCreated: onMapCreated),
    );
  }

  Widget _dropDownButton() {
    return Positioned(
        top: 40,
        right: 15,
        left: 15,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: TextFormField(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return PlacePicker(
                      apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                      initialPosition: currentPostion,
                      useCurrentLocation: true,
                      selectInitialPosition: true,
                      usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
                      onPlacePicked: (result) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedPlace = result;
                          locationController.text =
                              selectedPlace.formattedAddress;
                          controllers.animateCamera(
                            CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                              CameraPosition(
                                  target: LatLng(
                                      result.geometry.location.lat ?? 0.00,
                                      result.geometry.location.lng ?? 0.00),
                                  zoom: 20.0),
                            ),
                          );
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            readOnly: true,
            enableInteractiveSelection: false,
            // will disable paste operation
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            onChanged: (location) {
              setState(() {
                currentAddress = location;
              });
            },
            controller: locationController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: InkWell(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add_location,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 20,
                ),
              ),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
              hintText: 'Please choose a Address',
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _searchbar() {
    return Positioned(
      top: 100.0,
      right: 15.0,
      left: 15.0,
      child: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0x10000000),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1.5,
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: BlocBuilder<ProviderServiceBloc, ProviderServiceState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            OurList = state.services;
            _dropdownTestItems = buildDropdownTestItems(state.services);

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                underline: SizedBox.shrink(),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.white54,
                ),
                hint: Text(
                  'Search For the Service',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                value: _selectedTest,
                items: _dropdownTestItems,
                onChanged: onChangeDropdownTests,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
    
  }
```

Comment: Try to wrap _buildGoogleMap(context) Widget with Flexible.

Comment: Tried Not Working

Answer (score 0):

So after searching for almost 4 hours I found that its known issue for Flutter 3.0. So I have to downgrade my flutter version to 2.10.5 after that this issue is fixed for me.